# Guild Member Update Log Channel With Nicknames and Avatar

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to log when a member has been updated for example a new avatar or nickname. I can log it to a console but when I try to send it to a channel it fails. There are no errors in console. I have tried using multiple accounts and different channels but still no result or any errors in console.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {

    const guild = newMember.guild;

    var Changes = {
        unknown: 0,
        addedRole: 1,
        removedRole: 2,
        username: 3,
        nickname: 4,
        avatar: 5
    }
    var change = Changes.unknown

    var removedRole = ''
    oldMember.roles.every(function (value) {
        if (newMember.roles.cache.find('id', value.id) == null) {
            change = Changes.removedRole
            removedRole = value.name
        }
    })

    var addedRole = ''
    newMember.roles.every(function (value) {
        if (oldMember.roles.cache.find('id', value.id) == null) {
            change = Changes.addedRole
            addedRole = value.name
        }
    })

    if (newMember.user.username != oldMember.user.username) {
        change = Changes.username
    }

    if (newMember.nickname != oldMember.nickname) {
        change = Changes.nickname
    }

    if (newMember.user.avatarURL() != oldMember.user.avatarURL()) {
        change = Changes.avatar
    }

    var log = guild.channels.cache.get(`755216180603650059`)
    if (log != null) {
        switch (change) {
            case Changes.unknown:
                log.send('**[User Update]** ' + newMember)
                break
            case Changes.addedRole:
                log.send('**[User Role Added]** ' + newMember + ': ' + addedRole)
                break
            case Changes.removedRole:
                log.send('**[User Role Removed]** ' + newMember + ': ' + removedRole)
                break
            case Changes.username:
                log.send('**[User Username Changed]** ' + newMember + ': Username changed from ' +
                    oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator + ' to ' +
                    newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator)
                break
            case Changes.nickname:
                log.send('**[User Nickname Changed]** ' + newMember + ': ' +
                    (oldMember.nickname != null ? 'Changed nickname from ' + oldMember.nickname +
                        +newMember.nickname : 'Set nickname') + ' to ' +
                    (newMember.nickname != null ? newMember.nickname + '.' : 'original username.'))
                break
            case Changes.avatar:
                log.send('**[User Avatar Changed]** ' + newMember)
                break
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: you should be using `!==` instead of `!=`

Answer (score 0):

**Based off Levi_OP's comment**

```
if (a != b) {
       //...
    }
```

needs to turn into:

```
 if (a !== b) {
       //...
    }
```